# Debugger for Ionic Framework

Tags: debugging, firefox, ionic-framework

Fellows I am having a huge trouble with an project in Ionic and I want to use a dedugger in order to solve more effficiently.

Do you know how to use a debuggger in order to achieve that;

If the answer is the firefox debugger how I will use it in order to debug my application?

Comment: In the console/command prompt use `ionic serve` , then go to the URL provided in the console, and open up developer tools.. (F12).. You should be able to navigate to source tab.. : http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mozilla Firefox, [the following are different ways to set a breakpoint within the JavaScript code in the debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint).

[image]

---

For Google Chrome, since this is the JavaScript you can also use [Debugging with breakpoints (Debugging JavaScript)](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). This will help you a lot.

[image]

More about debugging: [How to Properly Debug Your Ionic Application](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-properly-debug-your-ionic-application/).